# How do I create a by-value iterator on the stack?

Tags: iterator, rust

I can create a consuming iterator in the heap:

```
vec![1, 10, 100].into_iter()
```

I can also create an iterator on the stack that borrows the elements:

```
[1, 10, 100].iter()
```

But if I write this:

```
[1, 10, 100].into_iter()
```

This is not a consuming iterator because `[T; _]::into_iter` does not exist: `IntoIterator` is only implemented for the borrowed version (aka slice). Is there a simple way (preferably in the `std` lib) to create a consuming iterator on the stack?

---

I know that `[1, 10, 100].iter().cloned()` can be done, but this requires the items to be clonable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Rust 1.53 (2021 Edition)

Starting from Rust 2021 Edition, calling [`into_iter()` on an array](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/edition-guide/rust-2021/IntoIterator-for-arrays.html) always provides a consuming by-value iterator. This means that the example provided in the question would work as originally desired.

```rust
[1, 10, 100].into_iter()
```

#### Rust 1.53 (other Editions)

In Rust 2015 or 2018 editions, the code above will still resolve to `(&[1, 10, 100]).into_iter()`, but any other syntax will provide a consuming iterator, regardless of edition.

```rust
for x in [1, 10, 100] {
}
```

```rust
IntoIterator::into_iter([1, 10, 100])
```

#### Rust 1.51

[`std::array::IntoIter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/array/struct.IntoIter.html) provides a by-value iterator for arrays. This API was made available alongside baseline support for const generics (see [Rust 1.51 announcement blog post](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2021/03/25/Rust-1.51.0.html#arrayintoiter-stabilisation)).

```
std::array::IntoIter::new([1, 10, 100])
```

#### Rust < 1.51

You can have a macro which wraps the values in a [`once`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/fn.once.html) iterator and [chains](https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.chain) them together:

```rust
macro_rules! value_iter {
    () => {
        std::iter::empty()
    };
    ($v: expr, $( $rest: expr ), +) => {
        std::iter::once($v).chain(
            value_iter!($($rest),*)
        )
    };
    ($v: expr) => {
        std::iter::once($v)
    };
}
```

Using:

```rust
#[derive(Debug, PartialEq)]
struct Foo;

let it = value_iter![Foo, Foo, Foo];

let all: Vec<_> = it.collect();
assert_eq!(all, vec![Foo, Foo, Foo]);
```

A known drawback is that the iterator will not be an exact-size iterator, and so the compiler might miss some obvious optimizations.

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e6003a6be56dc3af4cdb523716c8d2ea)

Answer (score 5):

> Is there a simple way (preferably in the `std` lib) to create a consuming iterator on the stack?

No.

> Is there a <s>simple</s> way <s>(preferably in the std lib)</s> to create a consuming iterator on the stack?

Yes.  Use a crate like [`stack`](https://crates.io/crates/stack) or [`smallvec`](https://crates.io/crates/smallvec), which provide array types that implement `IntoIterator`.

Answer (score 3):

Very ugly, but technically works:

```
for s in [
    Some(String::from("hello")),
    Some(String::from("goodbye"))
].iter_mut().map(|option| option.take().unwrap()) {
    let s: String = s;
    println!("{}", s);
}
```

You can use a macro that achieves this in a prettier way:

```
macro_rules! iter {
    [ $( $item:expr ),+ ] => {{
        [ $( Some($item), )+ ]
        .iter_mut()
        .map(|o| o.take().unwrap())
    }};
    // Rule to allow a trailing comma:
    [ $( $item:expr, )+ ] => {{
        iter![ $( $item ),+ ]
    }};
}

fn main() {
    for s in iter![String::from("hello"), String::from("goodbye")] {
        println!("{}", s);
    }
}
```