# Is there a way to initialize an iterator with a list of elements in Rust?

Tags: rust, iterator

I was wandering if there is a way to initialize an Iterator sequence with a list of items (similar to how you would initialize a `Vector<String>` using `vec![1, 2, 3]`).

I've tried searching online for something similar to what I require, but found nothing. I am aware of the existence of this feature in other languages (such as Java's `Stream.of`).

Here is my use case (taken from a variation of the minigrep example explained in the Rust Book):

```rust
...

pub fn grep<'a>(to_search_into: &'a str, pattern: &'a str) -> impl Iterator<Item = &'a str> {
    to_search_into.lines()
        .filter(move |line| line.contains(pattern))
}

...

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    #[test]
    fn one_result() {
        let test_string = "\
I am Grogg the everlasting
The great potato eater of old
Beware my ravenous maws.";

        assert_eq!(
            grep(test_string, "Grogg"),
            // what should go here?
            iter!["Grogg"]
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no much sense to add the `iter!` macro when you can just write `vec![...].iter()`. Under the hood, any implementation will do the same.

Comment: I think it is a rather bad idea to compare iterators in tests. Iterators change their content if being consumed, which makes failure reporting a problem. And there is no generic equals on `Iterators`. Rather collect the results into a vector and compare it with a vector.

Comment: @CoronA It perfectly ok to compare two iterator. https://docs.rs/itertools/0.8.0/itertools/fn.assert_equal.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create a by-value iterator on the stack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52605781/how-do-i-create-a-by-value-iterator-on-the-stack)

Comment: @Zefick Consider having a look at the proposed duplicate. There do exist implementations which do not have to allocate any heap memory.